# How to use the clearInterval() function to us?

Tags: javascript

Cannot terminate the `setInterval` I created in launch. It works until the time is up. I want to use `clearInterval (interval)` operation in `next()` function and `prev()` function. How should I do this? When I click forward, I want `clearInterval(interval)` to run this, but I couldn't.

```js
function launch() {

  thisTimeline = document.getElementsByClassName('story-active-' + start)[0];

  var maxtime = 5000;
  var incremental = 100;
  var actualtime = 0;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    actualtime += incremental;
    var percentage = Math.ceil((100 / maxtime) * actualtime);
    thisTimeline.style.width = percentage + '%';
    if (percentage == 100) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      thisTimeline.style.width = "0%";
    }
  }, incremental);


}


function next() {
  // Set previous video timeline to 100% complete
  thisTimeline.style.width = '100%';
  // Advance play count to next video
  start++;
  // If next video doesn't exist (i.e. the previous video was the last) then close the Social Story popup
  if (start >= defaults.playlist.length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      close();
      return false;
    }, 400);
  } else {
    // Otherwise run the next video
    launch(start);
  }
}

function prev() {
  if (start != 0) {
    thisTimeline.style.width = '0%';
  }
  // Subtract play count to previous video
  start--;
  // If next video doesn't exist (i.e. the previous video was the last) then close the Social Story popup
  if (start < 0) {
    start = 0;
    return false;
  } else {
    // Otherwise run the previous video
    launch(start);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your prev() and next() have their own scopes.

Comment: @IagoCalazans I did not understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extension of @lagoCalazans comment.

What he is saying is that in your variable "interval" is created in your launch function. You need to make "interval" global in order to clear your setInterval.

Ex:

```
let interval = null; //global

function launch() {
    let tempInterval = setInterval(function() {
        //whatever code
    },100); 

    interval = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Hello");
    }, 100);
}

function clear() {
    //Since interval is global I can clear it when I call clear();
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

As you can see in the launch function "tempInterval" is limited to the scope of launch, therefore cannot be accessed anywhere else, but now since "interval" is global it can be accessed in any function.

Comment: Amazing explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a bit incomplete, so for illustrative purposes only I will assume you encapsulate those functions in a higher order function (like an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)) and will avoid writing that (also, some kind of global state or variable would do for an example).

First of all, `setInterval` will return an id which you would use later, so if you want to use it within `next` and `prev`, you need that value to be available to them.

So, in your example, you should **declare** `interval` outside `launch`, and **assign** a value to it inside:

```js
let interval

function launch() {
    // ...
    interval = setInterval(function() { ... })
}
```

and then use `interval` wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`launch`, `next` and `prev` are three separate functions. They do not reference the same `interval` because they don't share [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). Raise the scope of the `interval` variable.

```js
let interval = ''; // declared here, interval can be accessed by all functions

function launch() {
    // ...
    // remove the var before interval
    interval = setInterval( ... )
}

function next() {
    // ...
    // remove the var before interval
    interval = setInterval( ... )
}

function prev() {
   // ...
    // remove the var before interval
    interval = setInterval( ... )
}
```